# Camel Bindy Fixed Length with Complex Structures

Tags: java, apache-camel, bindy, fixed-length-record

I am trying to understand whether bindy is able to manage some of the complex structures I am being asked to use to model a fixed length row.

I have a model that has nested classes and one of the nested classes its self references a class that is linked at the parent level (which is entirely possible, its similar I guess to normalisation). 
So, for example you might have a class structure

`

```
class-A
 -> String
 -> class-b 
 -> class-c
    -> String
    -> class-b
    -> String
 -> class-d
 -> String
 -> String
```

`

In the above structure, class-b models a set of data that is present as an attribute on both class-A and class-c. It seems to me that this is impossible because "class-b" would need to have definitions for 2 different positions in the structure. Is this correct, is this a limitation on the Bindy format?

thanks
Paul

Comment: Take a look at BeanIO. I've used that for parsing a somewhat complex structure from a fixed length file. I can't say for sure it's going to work for you as your class representation here is rather abstract. I'm however quite sure Bindy is insufficient for your needs, at least from my experience.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will certainly give that a go.